# why doesn't this ear find his dependencies?

Tags: maven, ejb, war, ear

I just mavenised some project. I was using ant before and it has following structure:

MYPROJECT/
  pom.xml (ear)
  MYPROJECT-EJB
     pom.xml
  MYPROJECT-WAR
     pom.xml

If I build the ejb and jar projects, it works. If I clean everything and starts from the ear, it doesn't. Here is what I got with 'maven clean install' from jenkins:

> [WARNING] The POM for be.valuya.myproject:myproject-ejb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   is missing, no dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
>   be.valuya.myproject:myproject-war:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
>   dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
>   be.valuya.myproject:myproject-ws:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no
>   dependency information available

BTW, I don't know how it's supposed to find those dependencies, but that's what I'd want.

Here is my ear's pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.valuya.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>myproject</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <applicationName>myproject</applicationName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-war</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-ws</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is my ejb module's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.valuya.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>myproject-ejb</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
            <!-- note that ampersands in this URL are escaped because this is in an xml file -
                   un-escape them to use in browser 
            -->
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        </repository>         
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-annotation-plugin</id>
            <url>http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArguments>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</compilerArguments>
                            <processors >
                                <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                            </processors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a superpom. Much better, although still not perfect (but I'll ask in another question).